# Vimeo will impose the rate limit on your application

Tags: ios, upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

Recently, i have got the email from vimeo developers that vimeo will impose the rate limit on your application on august 08. I am worried about my application. What are the steps i need to perform before they impose the rate limit.

Let me tell you my application only upload the videos to vimeo in particular one account. I never fetch any other information using vimeo api. I am using following approach to upload video.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

I am using NSURLConnection to perform the uploading job. I have read the following guidelines for rate limiting.

https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

Should i need to worry about rate limiting for uploading job ? If yes, What should i make changes in my upload request ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but I doubt you ran into an issue.

Following the guidelines you linked should be all you need to worry about. Be sure to make use of the [json filters](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter) from that link and to use an exponential backoff if you do encounter a ratelimit response.